# How to convert ReadableStream into ReadStream in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, fs

I'm using nodemailer, and pdfmake to create a pdf, and send it in the email's attachments. I don't have too much experience with file handling in NodeJS, and I can't make it work.

See [example](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/0.1/examples/basics.js) where the file is saved. As I've checked the types, `createPdfKitDocument` returns an extension of `NodeJS.ReadableStream`.

In nodemailer I can include attachments as `Stream` or `Readable` [See documentation.](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/)

However, I'm not able to send the attachment without saving it, and give the path to the file.

I tried to provide the `ReadableStream` returned from `createPdfKitDocument` as is, it result in hanging promise. I tried to wrap it with `Readable.from()`, it didn't work. I tried to call `.read()` on the result, and it didn't result in hanging promise, but the pdf cannot be opened.

Any ideas how can I convert a `ReadableStream` to `Readable`, or `Buffer`?

Answer (score 5):

`NodeJS.ReadableStream` type streams are used in older NodeJS libraries and versions. You can use the `wrap` method in `Readable` to convert `NodeJS.ReadableStream` to Readable stream.

```
const { OldReader } = require('./old-api-module.js');
const { Readable } = require('node:stream');
const oreader = new OldReader(); // will return stream of NodeJS.ReadableStream
const myReader = new Readable().wrap(oreader);

myReader.on('readable', () => {
  myReader.read(); // etc.
});
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_wrap_stream. For additional info do refer this as well https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#compatibility-with-older-nodejs-versions