# How to convert ReadStream into ReadableStream in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, fetch-api

This question is the exact reverse of [converting a ReadableStream into a ReadStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905931/how-to-convert-readablestream-into-readstream-in-nodejs).

- `ReadStream` is a structure used in Node.js
- `ReadableStream` is a structure [brought by the web platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams)

With the advent of non-Node.js runtimes such as Deno or the "Edge runtime" in Next.js, it can be useful to convert a Node.js specific `ReadStream` into a generic `ReadableStream`.

This is for instance useful to send files from a Next.js route handler, see [this discussion on Next.js GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15453#discussioncomment-6226391).

I've drafted a piece of code like so:

```js
const downloadStream = fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath);
    const readStream = new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        return pump();
        function pump() {
          return downloadStream.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
            if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
            }
            // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
            controller.enqueue(value);
            return pump();
          });
        }
      },
    });
```

I am in the process of testing it.

Edit: the problem with this first draft is that [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) `read()` method doesn't return a promise, as mentioned by @Mahesh in the comments.

Here is a second try:

```js
    const downloadStream = fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath);
    const readStream = new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        return pump();
        function pump() {
          const buf = downloadStream.read() as Buffer
          if (buf === null) {
            controller.close();
            return;
          }
          controller.enqueue(buf.toString());
          return pump();
        }
      },
    });
```

It gives me a null buffer immediately despite the file weighing 344 bytes. When I call `isPaused()`, the stream doesn't seem to be paused. Calling `pause()` doesn't fix my issue, neither adding an explicit size of 1 byte to `read()`.

I also get a weird error from Next.js:

```
- error Error: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:711:14)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:454:19)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

Are there simpler solutions, syntax-wise?

Comment: Its been long but I think the Node.js `ReadableStream` `read` method does not return a Promise, but the chunk of data directly. To get chunks of data asynchronously, you can use the readable event and the read method in combination

Comment: You are right, my current code doesn't do anything because of this. I am trying to figure the right syntax. Some insights: it seem all stream start in "paused mode", in this mode I can call "read()" and check if the response is null or not to see if there is more data. Docs are here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a working syntax but still lacking some details.

1. We want to be able to read a file using an imperative syntax, instead of relying on the traditional "data" event.

```js
/**
 * From https://github.com/MattMorgis/async-stream-generator
 */
async function* nodeStreamToIterator(stream) {
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
        yield chunk;
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with generators so I am not sure of:

- why we can apply the "of" operator to a Node.js `ReadableStream`?
- what `for await` means here?

But at least this syntax let's us consume the stream in loops.

2. Now we want to convert the iterator into a web platform `ReadStream`.

```
/**
 * Taken from Next.js doc
 * https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#streaming
 * Itself taken from mozilla doc
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#convert_async_iterator_to_stream
 * @param {*} iterator 
 * @returns {ReadableStream}
 */
function iteratorToStream(iterator) {
    return new ReadableStream({
        async pull(controller) {
            const { value, done } = await iterator.next()

            if (done) {
                controller.close()
            } else {

                controller.enqueue(new Uint8Array(value))
            }
        },
    })
}
```

Notice the "Uint8Array": this doesn't seem to be needed in all scenarios, but encoding may be required on some platforms, I needed this conversion in Next.js. See [this discussion on Next.js github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38736).

Finally we can use this stream in a `Response` just to see how it works:

```js
// highWaterMark affects the chunk size, here I use a small size to simulate many chunks
const nodeStream = fs.createReadStream("./.gitignore", { highWaterMark: 8 })
const iterator = nodeStreamToIterator(nodeStream)
const webStream = iteratorToStream(iterator)

const res = new Response(webStream)
const blob = await res.blob()
console.log(await blob.text())
```

Comment: In short, `for..of` construction can be applied to any object that has [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) and `for await..of` respectively can be applied to any [async iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncIterator). Streams are [compatible](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streams-compatibility-with-async-generators-and-async-iterators) with async iterators that's why you can use `for await`.